# Send information to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a **HTML** form and need to send the user input information to another HTML page using **Javascript**. But I'm don't know how to send this information to appear in the other page.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Answer (score 1):

Add all data to URL (send via _GET) and in next page parse url `window.location.search`. More info about parsing url [HERE](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html)

Comment: For example, I want to call the another page by URl "http://test.html". I need to make this: "http://test.html"+name" ?

Comment: @RafaelFonseca google for `_GET` method: `test.html?paramName=paramVal&paramName2=paramVal2`